# How to implement foreach in flink?

Tags: apache-flink

I need to use foreach in flink.
Is there anyone that can show an example about how to use the map() in flink to implement the  foreach in spark?

Answer (score 1):

Using map() as a replacement for foreach() should probably work - you can just put your foreach code in map() and then return the original element at the end of the function.

If you are not interested in the content of the data stream after the "foreach" and you only need the side effects, perhaps it's worth using or implementing a sink instead. For example if the requirement is to insert the data into a database or a messaging system, or to a file, sink is likely a better choice.

Comment: Advantage of using `map()` is that accepts a lambda. Is there anything similar to a sink which can be used with a simple lambda? We're heavily using `.print()` calls and would like to replace them by Log statements, but if possible in a simple and clean lambda instead of writing an own class.